# Lucene 4.0 IndexWriter updateDocument for Numeric Term

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I just wanted to know how it is possible to to update (delete/insert) a document based on a numeric field.
So far I did this:

```
LuceneManager.updateDocument(writer, new Term("id",  NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(sentenceId)), newDoc);
```

But now with Lucene 4.0 the NumericUtils class has changed to [this](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html#intToPrefixCoded%28int,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef%29) which I don't really understand.
Any help?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you were transforming numbers with NumericUtils manually, rather than using a [NumericField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html)?

Comment: Well because the IndexWriter wants a Term, and I didn't know any other way to create a Term for a Numeric Field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend, if possible, it would be better to store an ID as a keyword string, rather than a number.  If it is simply a unique identifier, indexing as a keyword makes much more sense.  This removes any need to mess with numeric formatting.

If it is actually being used as a number, then you might need to perform the update manually.  That is, search for and fetch the document you wish to update, delete the old document with [tryDeleteDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#tryDeleteDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader,%20int%29), and then add the updated version with [addDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocument%28java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer%29).  This is basically what updateDocument does anyway, to my knowledge.

The first option would certainly be the better way, though.  A non-numeric field to use as an update ID would make life easier.

Comment: You are right having the key as a string value would be cool, but this would mean a major refactoring throughout my code and reindexing the corpus, for which I sadly don't have time. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

With Lucene 5.x, this could be solved by code below:

```
    int id = 1;
    BytesRefBuilder brb = new BytesRefBuilder();
    NumericUtils.intToPrefixCodedBytes(id, 0, brb);
    Term term = new Term("id", brb.get());
    indexWriter.updateDocument(term, doc); // or indexWriter.deleteDocument(term);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way:

First you must set the `FieldType`'s numeric type:

```
FieldType TYPE_ID = new FieldType();
...
TYPE_ID.setNumericType(NumericType.INT);
TYPE_ID.freeze();
```

and then:

```
int idTerm = 10;
BytesRef bytes = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(id, 0, bytes);
Term idTerm = new Term("id", bytes);
```

and now you'll be able to use `idTerm` to update the doc.

Answer (score 0):

With Lucene 4, you can now create [IntField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntField.html), [LongField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongField.html), [FloatField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FloatField.html) or [DoubleField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DoubleField.html) like this:

```
document.add(new IntField("id", 6, Field.Store.NO));
```

To write the document once you modified it, it's still:

```
indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("pk", "<pk value>"), document);
```

**EDIT:**
And here is a way to make a query including this numeric field:

```
// Query <=> id <= 7
Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("id", Integer.MIN_VALUE, 7, true, true);
TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 10);
```

Comment: So I just use the toString() value of the Integer/Float/Long/Double object?

Comment: No, all these fields have a method [numericValue()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#numericValue()) that returns the number of the underlying field. To know which type the number is (int, long...), you either use `instanceof` or use [FieldType.NumericType](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.NumericType.html)

Comment: I don't think this can work this way. If I have the query = new TermQuery(new Term(LUCENE_FIELD_ID, new IntField(LUCENE_FIELD_ID, 1, Store.YES).stringValue())); then the query looks like "id:1" which does not return any results. Where as  NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(1) returns results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way to query has changed as well. Now, instead of a TermQuery, you should use a [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html).

Comment: Thx. I figured this also out today. Makes life much easier. :) I still don't really get how to update my document based on a "integer-term"

Comment: TermQuery can't be used to `updateDocuments` 10 years later I'm afraid

Comment: I guess Lucene 4 hasn't changed much in the last 10 years. But I also hope people are now using newer versions ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of Lucene 4.0.0](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html), the ID field must to be used with StringField class:

"A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is indexed as a single token. For example this might be used for a 'country' field **or an 'id' field**, or any field that you intend to use for sorting or access through the field cache."

I had the same problem as you and I solved it by making this change. After that, my update and delete worked perfectly.